# Kth Ranked Element Among 2 Unsorted Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Let us suppose we have two arrays A[] and B[]. Each array contains n distinct integers which are not sorted. We need to find kth ranked element in the union of the 2 arrays in the most efficient way possible.
(Please dont post answers about merging the arrays and then sorting them to return kth index in the merged array)

Comment: Distinct in the sense that they are unique,  for example A[8 3 2 4 12] and B[6 11 1 5 9]. All elements are integers less than 10000000 and the elements need not be consecutive.

Comment: It was just an example. We need to solve for a general case of unsorted arrays. I have updated the comment to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the Kth item, in O(N) time, where N is the sum of the sizes of the arrays. Obviously, you treat the two arrays as a single large array.

Comment: I know this method but I need a better complexity

Comment: There is no better complexity than O(N) for finding the Kth item in unsorted list.

Answer (score 2):

Union of arrays can be done in linear time. I am skipping that part.

You can use the `partition`() algorithm which is used in the `quick sort`. In quick sort, the function will have to recurse two branches. However here we will just conditionally invoke the recursive call and thus only 1-branched recursion.

**Main concept**: `partition`() will place the chosen `PIVOT` element at its appropriate sorted position. Hence we can use this property to select that half of the array in which we are interested and just recurse on that half. This will prevent us from sorting the entire array.

I have written the below code based on the above concept. Assumption rank = 0 implies the smallest element in the array.

```
void swap (int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int partition (int a[], int start, int end)
{
    /* choose a fixed pivot for now */
    int pivot = a[end];
    int i = start, j;

    for (j = start; j <= end-1; j++) {
        if (a[j] < pivot) {
            swap (&a[i], &a[j]);
            i++;
        }
    } 
    /* Now swap the ith element with the pivot */
    swap (&a[i], &a[end]);
    return i;
}

int find_k_rank (int a[], int start, int end, int k)
{
    int x = partition (a, start, end);
    if (x == k) {
        return a[x];
    } else if (k < x) {
        return  find_k_rank (a, start, x-1, k);
    } else {
        return find_k_rank (a, x+1, end, k);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {10,2,7,4,8,3,1,5,9,6};
    int N = 10;
    int rank = 3;
    printf ("%d\n", find_k_rank (a, 0, N-1, rank));
}
```